# Minimum hardware requirements for LAMP server

Tags: hardware, linux, lamp

I am planning to start my own shared server running LINUX and PHP and MySQL. What are the minimum hardware requirements to get things running?

**Edit:** The server will run INNO_DB based databases, needs to serve at least 10,000 unique daily visits, and handle peak loads of approximately 300 visits/second!

Comment: I would like to say there are no stupid questions.  But...why would you plan on getting into this business with little to no experience (based on the nature of your question)?

Comment: i'm planning to start my site on my own server !

Comment: "NOW WHAT?" now what to do ? where to start ? ...

Comment: I can run those things from my cell phone or a ten year old desktop computer. Literally. The question is how much load could they handle? What kind of sites will you host and how much traffic do you need to serve? You need to specify those requirements before this question is answerable.

Comment: One unoptimized query can bring down a high performance server. The only way to know your requirements is to setup the server and monitor it. Most experienced developers can intuitively guess the requirements. But that intuition is based on their in-depth knowledge of their application.

Comment: Something in your requirements doesn't add up. 300 visits per second is 25.9 million a day. Across 10,000 unique visits each visitor is making 2,590 requests. Can we assume you mean the PEAK load is 300 per second? What about the average load? Did you just make up your numbers based on how much traffic you would like to have to your site?

Comment: also 300 visits per second is a MAJOR site. Not hugh, but not small. Database is a joke "inno_db databases". Nce. Says nothing. Back to horsepowers. I have a server with ONE databae, ONE app using it. 800gb, maxing out 64gb ram and a lot of io... and i have 100 database on another smaller server. Depends on the database.

Answer (score 3):

> what will be the lowest hardware requirements to get things running?

How many horse powers does a car need?

Same answer:

DEPENDS ON REQUIREMENTS.

You dont state any. Which emans likely my mobile phone has too many horsepowers. How much traffic? Waht IO do you need? How much ram do you need? YOu have to tell us, not we you. We dont know your application.

Comment: truthfully, you can run a LAMP stack on an embedded mips processor at 200mhz with 16mb of ram or less... (yes, I've done it)  It runs like crap... but it did work.  As for Sourav's provided stats on usage... how many unique visits & number of visits per second are very moot.  In most cases, the MySQL instance will be the biggest hog of resources and that depends on other requirements like the number of rows in tables, the number of indexes, and the number of queries being run per second.  Apache & php typically sit idle waiting on the database.  (assuming your code is well optimized)

Answer (score 0):

So, as TomTom said, the answer depends greatly on your requirements, and they don't seem very well-defined.  Do you know what your requirements look like in detail, or is this still in an exploratory phase?  Do you have hardware already available for use, or are you planning purchasing?

If you're still trying to determine your requirements, and especially if you'd need to buy hardware, I'd strongly suggest experimenting on a "cloud" provider like Amazon EC2 before trying to build on your own hardware.  This will allow you to try several different levels of service to get a rough idea of your needs.  I've done this kind of experimental scaling several times myself, and while it doesn't always translate 1-to-1, it's often been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For what purposes it will be used?

1. Video streaming
2. File Storage
3. Some news page
4. Havy load pages with images/flash etc
5. Clear text/css/java pages that can be easy cached with some tools

Please give some details.

Comment: light weight social network with very little amount of picture